# transform feedback and empty buffer objects

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

Is it safe to assume that starting transform feedback and issuing a `draw*` command with 0 primitive count and a bound VAO referencing a 0 byte-sized buffer object, will result in an empty transform feedback object (whatever content its buffer object could have) so that a `DrawTransformFeedback` will not draw anything? Is it safe to assume that the same would happen starting/ending transform feedback without issuing any draw command?

Comment: "*I am not finding anything relevant in the specs that explicitly forbids or limits such behavior.*" Then what's your question, exactly? The specification states what is possible and what is not. If it does not say that something results in an error or undefined behavior, then you apply the text in accord with what it says *does* happen.

Comment: I may have overlooked the specs and missed something, or some user may have had direct experience on particular hardware that goes against my results. Lastly, the specs do not cover these situations: it does not say anything about an empty transform begin/end, and I dont think this means the resulting transform feedback object will be empty (considering it could have been filled before). I DO think the resulting object will be empty, and it makes sense, but maybe empty transform begin/end will simply leave the transform feedback object untouched on some hardware, thus not clearing it.

Comment: since the specs DO explicitly consider negative buffer size, but do not say anything regarding 0 buffer size, I assume it is allowed to allocate a 0 bytes sized buffer and use it to issue a 0 primitive count draw, so I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole "bound VAO referencing a 0 byte-sized buffer object" part is a non-sequitur. You don't have to put *any* buffer objects in a VAO; you can shut off all of the attribute arrays by `glDisableVertexAttribArray`-ing all of them (or just not enabling any).

In any case, the spec is pretty clear on this:

> Note that the vertex count is from the number of vertices recorded to the selected vertex stream during the transform feedback operation. If no outputs belonging to the selected vertex stream are recorded, the corresponding vertex count will be zero even if complete primitives were emitted to the selected stream.

If no vertices were recorded, then the vertex count will be zero.

Comment: I am clearly talking about a situation in which I have one or more 0 sized buffer objects enabled by the corresponding attrib arrays, so yes, you can shut them off by disabling but no, it is not this the case, and since the vao is used during the transform feedback, I do not agree that it is a non-sequitur. Thank you for your answer anyway. I saw that paragraph but I was not sure that the number of recorded vertices is 0 if there have not been any draw calls

Comment: @user815129: "*I do not agree that it is a non-sequitur*" Well, 1) there's no reason to ever create a zero-length buffer object, let alone use it in a VAO, and 2) the contents of a VAO have *nothing to do* with how transform feedback objects work (at least, not in terms of vertex counts). So yes, it was a non-sequitur, just like mentioning whether or not any glDrawBuffers were set in such a rendering operation.

Comment: I do not agree. 1) there may be reasons to create a zero-length buffer object, and to use it in a VAO, even if you do not have any result, for the same reason C++ standard allows new int[0] and require a delete[] on the returned pointer, even if unusable. The fact that no valid reason crosses your mind does not mean there are none. 2) it is not a non-sequitur since the VAO influences the results of the buffer object bound to the transform feedback object. cfr http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic) Mentioning if glDraw* calls are made is the very core of the question.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but IMHO it is still an interpretation of the specs, which always refers to an output of some kind. I am not really sure that performing no draw _at all_ can be considered a 0 vertex output

Comment: @user815129: That's like saying that, if you can use arithmetic to add 100 and 1, you can't use the same math for 1000 and 1. How many vertices were output in a begin/end feedback with no drawing? Zero. How many vertices will glDrawTransformFeedback draw? The number that were output. That's not an "interpretation"; it's *what the spec says*.

Comment: _How many vertices were output in a begin/end feedback with no drawing? Zero_ I agree with you, but I dont think it is in the specs

Comment: @user815129: The spec explains exactly what it captures: the vertices output to various streams. Vertices output to a stream come from various shader invocations that write streams. If you don't draw anything, then you have zero shader invocations. Zero shader invocations means zero vertices written to various streams. And zero vertices written to various streams means zero vertices output. Just *follow the data*. The spec doesn't have to special case what happens when you don't do anything; it's implicit based on the fact that you didn't do anything.

Comment: @user815129: Similarly, the specification doesn't state that using `GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD` makes the query count of samples passed zero. It doesn't *have to*, because no samples can pass if you discard the primitive before they're rasterized.